# Can qTip chase after mouse position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, mousemove

I want to use [qTip http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) in my website and I want the tooltip to "chase" after the mouse. That is the tooltip balloon should display next to the cursor and remain next to it even if it moves.

What's the best method to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup.

In your options (the hash passed to the qtip() method:

```
position: { target: 'mouse' }
```